# Subtracting dates in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

Trying to create a new column in a dataframe that shows number of days between now and a past date. So far I have below code but it returns 'days' + a timestamp.  How can I get just the number of days?

```
import pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
excel1['days_old'] = now - excel1['Start Time']
```

Returns:

`92 days 08:08:06.667518`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also worked for me

```
import datetime
import pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
excel1['days_old'] = (now - excel1['Start Time']).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Answer (score 1):

excel1['days_old'] will hold "timedeltas".  To get them to the day difference, just use ".days" like this:

```
import pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
excel1['days_timedelta'] = now - excel1['Start Time']
excel1['days_old'] = excel1['days_timedelta'].days
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *Start Time* column is of *datetime* type, run:

```
(pd.Timestamp.now() - df['Start Time']).dt.days
```